# Any chance to check wich cells were edited?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check which cells from gridview were edited?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585463/how-to-check-which-cells-from-gridview-were-edited)

I would like to know how can I check if cells from gridview were edited or not.

Comment: you don't need 3 separate post for one question 
dupe -http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588332/how-to-check-edited-cells-in-gridview-then-add-their-values-into-a-textbox
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585463/how-to-check-which-cells-from-gridview-were-edited

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RowUpdated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowupdated.aspx) event to check if by the [GridViewUpdatedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdatedeventargs.aspx) parameter. There are two properties called OldValues and NewValues, you can check what were updated  (on old values are diferents from news values).

Comment: I know that , but I don't know how to check which cells were updated

Comment: Look this sample at DisplayValues method, you can add a "if" statement to each item (by index) to check if it's diferent. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdatedeventargs.aspx

Comment: Yes I know but I need something global without adding if , if if..etc..too many if conditions

Comment: there are only two-three if statements to use if you understood what we are trying to tell you. You seem to be stubborn and refuse to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Check this part of code from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewupdatedeventargs.newvalues%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

```
void DisplayValues(OrderedDictionary newValues, OrderedDictionary oldValues)
  {

    Message.Text += "<br/></br>";

    // Iterate through the new and old values. Display the
    // values on the page.
    for (int i = 0; i < oldValues.Count; i++)
    {
      Message.Text += "Old Value=" + oldValues[i].ToString() +
        ", New Value=" + newValues[i].ToString() + "<br/>";
    }

    Message.Text += "</br>";

  }
```

You can use that to say

```
txtbox.Text = "name changed from" + oldValues[0].ToString() +
            " to " + newValues[0].ToString();
```

I think this should help you.